# Events Conversions in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I see in the documentation at firebase website that 15 events can be marked as conversions in the Events section apart from the default events.

Can I mark more than 15 events as conversions in Firebase?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is pretty unclear. Can you include a quote from what you are seeing or perhaps a direct link to the documentation so we can understand what you are asking? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot exceed the limits.  You are free to [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) if you would like the product to change in some way to meet your requirements.